# SQL Query Not Being Updated

Tags: android, sql

I am fairly new to Android application development. Recently, I've been honing my skills by developing a GPA calculator by myself. At the moment, I have the following code which helps me obtain the cumulative GPA of a person's grades

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DataManager sqLiteHelper;
Cursor cursor;
Button Delete, Edit;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabaseObj;
String SQLiteDataBaseQueryHolder ;

TextView semester,gpa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gpa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGPA);
    groupgpa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewgroupGPA);
    /*semester = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSEMESTER);*/

    SQLiteDataBaseBuild();
    sqLiteHelper = new DataManager(this);

    SQLiteTableBuild();
    double groupgpa2 =semestralgpa();

    groupgpa.setText(Double.toString(groupgpa2));

    double gpa2 = totalgpa();

    gpa.setText(Double.toString(gpa2));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.about:
            // Do Something
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"About...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.addsem:
            // Do Something
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ADDSEMESTERACTIVITY.class));
            return true;

        case R.id.allgrade:
            // Do Something
            startActivity(new Intent(this, DISPLAYALLGRADEACTIVITY.class));
            return true;


    }
    return false;

}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
/*        switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.photoalbum:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, PhotoAlbum.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }*/
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    totalgpa();

    super.onResume();
}





public void OpenSQLiteDataBase(){

    sqLiteDatabaseObj = openOrCreateDatabase(DataManager.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

}
public void SQLiteDataBaseBuild(){

    sqLiteDatabaseObj = openOrCreateDatabase(DataManager.DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

}

public void SQLiteTableBuild(){

    sqLiteDatabaseObj.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+DataManager.TABLE_NAME+"("+DataManager.Table_Column_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "+DataManager.Table_Column_1_SUBJECT+" VARCHAR, "+DataManager.Table_Column_2_GRADE+" VARCHAR, "+DataManager.Table_Column_3_CREDIT+" INTEGER, "+DataManager.Table_Column_4_GCPRODUCT+" DECIMAL, "+DataManager.Table_Column_5_SEMESTER+" VARCHAR);");

}

public double totalgpa(){

    double gpa = 0;

    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit) FROM " + DataManager.TABLE_NAME +" group by Semester", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        gpa = cursor.getDouble(0);
    }
    return gpa;
}


}
```

The method to calculate GPA.

```
public double totalgpa(){

    double gpa = 0;

    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit) FROM " + DataManager.TABLE_NAME +"", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        gpa = cursor.getDouble(0);
    }
    return gpa;
}
```

It is able to show the sum available. However, if I were to add in more values, it would not update.
Could someone show me what am I doing wrong ?

Also if I were to run a method to obtain the semester's gpa by grouping by semester, I am only able to print out the gpa for 1 semester.

The method in question :

```
public double semestralgpa(){

    double gpa = 0;

    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit) FROM " + DataManager.TABLE_NAME +" group by Semester", null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        gpa = cursor.getDouble(0);
    }
    return gpa;
}
```

Comment: (1) In the `onResume` method, delete the line `totalgpa();` (2) After `Super.onResume();` line, add line `gpa.setText(Double.toString(totalgpa));`

Comment: Thank you. It is able to update now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you need to update the view (TextView) after retrieving the value in the `onResume` method.

Currently you have :-

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    totalgpa();
    super.onResume();
}
```

This only retrieves the new value. You should also let the super call do it's business and restore the activity. So instead of the above use :-

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    gpa.setText(Double.toString(totalgpa));
}
```

This retrieves the value and also applies it to the TextView in one line.

In regards to :-

> Also if I were to run a method to obtain the semester's gpa by
>   grouping by semester, I am only able to print out the gpa for 1
>   semester.

It sounds like you want to display a list of the grouped semestralgpa's, you could use :-

```
public String semestralgpa(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();    
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit) FROM " + DataManager.TABLE_NAME +" group by Semester", null);
    if(cursor.moveToNext()){

        // Add separator between values.
        if (cursor.getPosition() > 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(String.valueOf(cusror.getDouble(0)));
        // or sb.append(cursor.getString(0));
        // or sb.append(Double.toString(cursor.getDouble(0)));    
    }
    return sb.toString;
}
```

Note! The above isn't tested so may contain some errors.

---

You would then likely see that the list is just the gpa's with no indication of the Semester they are for. Therefore you might want/prefer :-

```
public String semestralgpa(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
    sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();    
    cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit) AS Semestergpa, Semester FROM " + DataManager.TABLE_NAME +" group by Semester", null);
    if(cursor.moveToNext()){

        // Add separator between values.
        if (cursor.getPosition() > 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(String.valueOf(cusror.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Semestergpa")));
        sb.append(" for ");
        sb.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Semester")));
        sb.append(".");    
    }
    return sb.toString;
}
```

### Notes

- AS Semestergpa renames the resultant column from  `sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit)` to `Semestergpa` (shown an an example)
- Using hard coded offsets can easily result in mistakes, hence why getColumnIndex has been shown. This gets the offset according to the column name. Using derived offsets would work if you were to use :-

  `cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT Semester, sum(gcproduct)/sum(credit) AS Semestergpa FROM " + DataManager.TABLE_NAME +" group by Semester", null);` (whilst **0** would now be the Semester)